# JSON: value of C depending of other values?

Tags: javascript

Given an object literal such :

```
var data = {
   { "A": 3, "B": 4, "C²": 25, "C": 5 } // hint: triangle
}
```

where there is a mathematical relation between values (C² = A² + B²).

Is there possible to have some 'inside operation' such:

```
var data = {
   { "A": 3, "B": 4, "C²": (Math.pow(A,2)+Math.pow(B,2)), "C": Math.sqrt("C²") } // hint: triangle
}
```

I will have a set of +200 A, B values, from which I wish to calculate the C value, to then reuse it.

If possible, **how to do so ?**

---

Edit: I use this as a local data, not as an exchange format crossing the web.

Comment: JSON is a data interchange format, it can't contain code. This is by design, there's enough security vulnerabilities stemming from the fact it gets parsed into JS `Object`s as it is.

Comment: umh. I guess you just killed my dream (question).

Comment: This is not valid JS object either. Anyway you are able to do that, but there are some tricks to apply, going to post an answer soon

Comment: Note: I use is as a local data, no as an exchange format crossing the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function buildTriangleObject(a, b) {
    var square = Math.pow(a, 2) + Math.pow(b, 2);
    return {
        A: a,
        B: b,
        "C²": square,
        C: Math.sqrt(square)
    };
}

var triangles = [],
    triangle = buildTriangleObject(3, 4), //Object
    stringified = JSON.stringify(triangle), //String, will be '{"A":3,"B":4,"C²":25,"C":5}'
    parsed = JSON.parse(stringified); //Object, equals triangle
triangles.push(triangle);
```

Doing what you're trying to achieve is a bit more complicated: you're trying to reference a variable of an object inside another object, which is a little silly IMHO(you can do that referencing the parent object and then the inner object, but it's a mess, believe me). This way you have a little helper function which creates the object for you and you're able to manipulate it in any way you prefer.

Since you were looking for a JSON representation of this, you can simply use `JSON.stringify` on `triangles` to get the JSON for the whole array, and then deserialize it simply by using `JSON.parse`.

**Note**: I used a string to define the `C²` property and you'll be able to retrieve it only via bracket notation, otherwise you'll get an `Unexpected token ILLEGAL` in your console.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible.

However, you could save there a value like `"operation" : "calculateTriangle"` and then perform actions depending on that value.